# Mule Catch exception strategy in subflow to restart subflow

Tags: java, mule

I have added a catch exception strategy inside a subflow, and I would like it to "restart" its subflow (as a goto, basically) whenever the catch is triggered.

So that it does something like this:
FTPSubflow->
   FTP->ERROR->Catch-> if (custom_retry_var > 0) > Restart FTPSubflow

I could have a java component in my catch to check that, but then I am not sure how to restart the subflow, and do it again. What I want to be sure is that when it restarts, if it succeeds a subsequent time, at the end of the subflow execution the execution of my regular flow will continue as normal, as it would have if a catch exception never happened.

Can Mule and a custom component be up to this?

Thanks!

Comment: After trying to run my code with a catch-exception-strategy element inside my subflow, it looks like you can't have one inside a subflow. How can I get my subflow to trigger a specific catch exception and restart the subflow in the exact same context as when it started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sub-flows` don't have their own exception handling. Exceptions triggered in sub-flow are processed by calling flows(main flow)

`Private flows` are another type of reusable flows, much similar to sub-flows but with a very different behavior in term of threading and exception handling. The primary reason for using a private flow instead of a sub-flow is to define in it a `different exception strategy` than from the calling flow (something that is impossible with a sub-flow).

Private flow is nothing but the main flow without the inbound endpoint. To start the flow again, make your flow main-flow, with an inbound endpoint and in your catch exception strategy, create a java component implementing *Callable* interface and use `muleClient.dispatch` to start flow again.

A sample component would be something like this:

```
import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;
import org.mule.api.client.MuleClient;

public class MyCustomComponent implements Callable {  


    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
      MuleClient muleClient = eventContext.getMuleContext().getClient();
      muleClient.dispatch("jms://my.queue", "Message Payload", null);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I actually converted my subflow to a synchronous flow, and the catch exception is actually triggered. Now do you know how to concretely write the java component to restart the subflow? Is there an example somewhere I could reuse? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like I can do a choice > check my custom retry variable, and then run the same flow again as a flow-ref. Looks like it works so far!